# juno doesn't recognise properties of generic subclasses

Tags: eclipse, jsf, generics, el

Juno is highlighting my property references as invalid since I added a parameterised class.

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseAction<viewDataClass extends AbstractViewData>

    protected viewDataClass viewData;

    public viewDataClass getViewData(){
       return viewData;
    }
    ....
}

public class SomeAction extends AbstractBaseAction<SomeViewData>
{
    public AbstractMaturingOptionsAction()
    {
        super(new SomeViewData());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setupViewData(){
        ....
    }
    ....
}

public class SomeViewData extends AbstractViewData

    String someProperty;

    public String getSomeProperty(){
        return someProperty;
    }
    ....
}

....

property="#{SomeAction.viewData.someProperty}"
```

Juno is highlighting someProperty

"someProperty cannot be resolved as a member of viewData"

Is this worth investigating, or should I just code it another way?

Comment: The problem is that JSF (and other classes will) treat the `viewData` attribute as a `AbstractViewData` instance instead of the specific child class. That explains why your IDE marks the `someProperty` attribute, because this attribute belongs to the child, not to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse builtin EL validation/autocomplete is indeed shortcoming.

Consider installing [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools). It properly recognizes properties in superclasses. Here's a screenshot as evidence that it does the job for me.

[image]

By the way, your `viewDataClass` naming convention is terrible. You should use a single letter capital like `V` or so.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will have a look at the JBoss Tools. I don't understand this single letter approach, but that is another story ;-)